# Django-Twilio Looping when trying to return twilio_resonse

Tags: django, twilio

The below code gets the digits of a previous `gather` method and then checks to see if the order exists and if it does asks the user to confirm the order one more time before taking them to a recording queue to allow them to attached a message to their order.

For some reason the after taking the user input of `1` it just loops back to `menu_option_3_evaluate_gather` method.  I can see the POST hit `menu_option_3_evaluate_gather_evaluate`.

Any ideas why this looping effect is happening?

```
@twilio_view
def menu_option_3_evaluate_gather(request):
    twilio_response = Response()
    digits = request.POST.get('Digits', '').strip('#').strip('*')
    print "digits == " + digits
    order = Orders.objects.using('woodmans').get(orderid=1234)#int(digits))
    if digits and order:
        with twilio_response.gather(numDigits=1, action="/menu_option_3_evaluate_gather_evaluate", method="POST", time_out=120) as g:
            g.say("You entered ")
            for number in digits:
                g.say(number)
            g.say("If this is accurate press one now or any other key to re enter your order i d.")
            g.pause(length=1)
            return twilio_response
    else:
        twilio_response.say("The order id entered is invalid.")
        return twilio_response

@twilio_view    
def menu_option_3_evaluate_gather_evaluate(request):
    twilio_response = Response()
    r = twiml.Response()
    digits = request.POST.get('Digits', '').strip('#').strip('*')
    print "menu_option_3_evaluate_gather_evaluate digits == " + digits
    if int(digits) == 1:
        twilio_response.say('After the beep leave your name a short message and a manager will return your call as soon as possible.')
        twilio_response.record(action="/new_order_vm?Orderid={0}".format(digits), method="GET", timeout=15, finishOnKey=None, maxLength=500, transcribe=False, transcribeCallback=None, playBeep=True)
    return twilio_response
    #else:
    #   return menu_option_3_evaluate_gather(request)
```

Comment: This is happening because you are comparing an integer `1` to a string `'1'` which is what you will get from the `POST` data. The two are not equal in Python.

Comment: I updated code.  Still same loop.   Also ``` print "menu_option_3_evaluate_gather_evaluate digits == " + digits``` isn't even printing.